# NumericUpDown with Unit | Custom control | Field padding

Tags: c#, winforms, label, custom-controls, padding

Im trying to create a custom control that inherits `NumericUpDown` to show a settable unit.

**This is (visually) what I've got so far:**

[image]

**My Code:** *Looks a bit long, but isnt doing that much*

```
class NumericUpDownUnit : NumericUpDown
{
    public event EventHandler ValueChanged;

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor creates a label
    /// </summary>
    public NumericUpDownUnit()
    {
        this.TextChanged += new EventHandler(TextChanged_Base);
        this.Maximum = 100000000000000000;
        this.DecimalPlaces = 5;

        this.Controls.Add(lblUnit);
        lblUnit.BringToFront();

        UpdateUnit();
    }

    public void TextChanged_Base(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(ValueChanged != null)
        {
            this.ValueChanged(sender, e);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// My designer property
    /// </summary>
    private Label lblUnit = new Label();
    [Description("The text to show as the unit.")]
    public string Unit
    {
        get
        {
            return this.lblUnit.Text;
        }
        set
        {
            this.lblUnit.Text = value;
            UpdateUnit();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// When unit has changed, calculate new label-size
    /// </summary>
    public void UpdateUnit()
    {
        System.Drawing.Size size = TextRenderer.MeasureText(lblUnit.Text, lblUnit.Font);
        lblUnit.Padding = new Padding(0, 0, 0, 3);
        lblUnit.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(size.Width, this.Height);
        lblUnit.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
        lblUnit.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
        lblUnit.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(this.Width-lblUnit.Width-17, 0);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// If text ends with seperator, skip updating text as it would parse without decimal palces
    /// </summary>
    protected override void UpdateEditText()
    {
        if (!this.Text.EndsWith(".") && !this.Text.EndsWith(","))
        Text = Value.ToString("0." + new string('#', DecimalPlaces));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Culture fix
    /// </summary>
    protected override void OnKeyPress(KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar.Equals('.') || e.KeyChar.Equals(','))
        {
            e.KeyChar = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator.ToCharArray()[0];
        }
        base.OnKeyPress(e);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// When size changes, call UpdateUnit() to recalculate the lable-size
    /// </summary>
    protected override void OnResize(EventArgs e)
    {
        UpdateUnit();
        base.OnResize(e);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Usability | On enter select everything
    /// </summary>
    protected override void OnEnter(EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Select(0, this.Text.Length);
        base.OnMouseEnter(e);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// If, when leaving, text ends with a seperator, cut it out
    /// </summary>
    protected override void OnLeave(EventArgs e)
    {
        if(this.Text.EndsWith(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator))
        {
            this.Text = this.Text.Substring(0, this.Text.Length - 1);
        }

        base.OnLeave(e);
    }
}
```

---

**My problem:**

The lable is currently covering the end of the box. So if a big value comes in (or the size is low) it gets covered by the label as seen in here:

[image]

I know that the `NumericUpDown` has something like a scroll-function when a typed in value is longer than the size of the inputbox. This is triggered at the end of the box.

Is there in any way the possibility of setting up something like **padding** for the text inside the box? For example setting the padding on the right to the size of my label?

*I like this custom control pretty much but this one last thing is annoying.*

---

*Unfortunately I dont know how to lookup the properties of an existing control as for example there is a method called `UpdateEditText()`. Maybe someone can tell me how to lookup this base functions/properties.*

**Thanks a lot!**

Comment: You're getting the "scroll" feature for free, but it only applies to the text the control renders.  You are simply overlaying a `Label` at a specific point.  I think you really want to try and supply the complete text back to the control, and not draw any text yourself.  That might mean you have manage both text and value, since the text would then be non-numeric.

Comment: @DonBoitnott That was my first thought. But then I realized Im already grabbing into the text with my decimal-fix. So splitting this topics wouldnt be that bad (for example by using a label). The accepted answer works well in here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NumericUpDown` is a control which inherits from [`UpDownBase`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/UpDownBase.cs,05edf813bc58c0d8) composite control. It contains an [`UpDownEdit`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/UpDownBase.cs,dba00527aa62642b) and an [`UpDownButtons`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/UpDownBase.cs,96e98136aa8a4ce4) control. The `UpDownEdit` is a `TextBox`. You can change appearance of the control and its children. For example, you can add a `Label` to the textbox control and dock it to the right of `TextBox`, then set text margins of textbox by sending an [`EM_SETMARGINS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761649(v=vs.85).aspx) message to get such result:

[image]

**Code**

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;
public class ExNumericUpDown : NumericUpDown
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, int wParam, int lParam);
    private const int EM_SETMARGINS = 0xd3;
    private const int EC_RIGHTMARGIN = 2;
    private Label label;
    public ExNumericUpDown() : base()
    {
        var textBox = Controls[1];
        label = new Label() { Text = "MHz", Dock = DockStyle.Right, AutoSize = true };
        textBox.Controls.Add(label);
    }
    public string Label
    {
        get { return label.Text; }
        set { label.Text = value; if (IsHandleCreated) SetMargin(); }
    }
    protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnHandleCreated(e);
        SetMargin();
    }
    private void SetMargin()
    {
        SendMessage(Controls[1].Handle, EM_SETMARGINS, EC_RIGHTMARGIN, label.Width << 16);
    }
}
```

Comment: Working great! Would you mind telling me how you created this gif? I dont think it've taken 1 hour for you. Topic related: So sad there is no `EC_LEFTMARGIN`. With this I could've set up a new property `UnitDock`.

Comment: **-** I use [ScreenToGif](https://screentogif.codeplex.com/) to record a selected area of the screen and save it as an animated gif. **-** To set left margin, define `private const int EC_LEFTMARGIN = 1;` then `SendMessage(Controls[1].Handle, EM_SETMARGINS, EC_LEFTMARGIN, label.Width);`

Comment: Btw, i was just stupid as I havnt seen `EC_RIGHTMARGIN` was a property you have defined for yourself. Self explaining.

Comment: They have different goals. The one in `OnHandleCreated` is for the first time the control created. The one in `Label` property is for next times when you change the label text at runtime. The first time you assign text to `Label` property the control handle is not created and we can not send message to it.