# Customizing Borders on a TextBox

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

So I have a `TextBox` in my WinForm that I would want to design. I would like to achieve a text box that has no border except for its bottom part, just like the one in the [Material Design Website](https://material.google.com/):

[image]

But I have a few problems. I don't know how to code this one. Is there any way to code it like the one we use in CSS, i.e. `border-bottom` or something?

Comment: [Change border color in TextBox C#](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39420512/3110834) - You can draw bottom-border and other borders using different colors. (Bottom white, others blue for example)

Comment: [TextBox with bottom border](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38403722/3110834) - Another simple option by just adding a control to `TextBox` controls collection.

Comment: I think I will use the second one. Thanks!

Comment: About the watermark you can follow such solution [Watermark TextBox in WinForms](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36534068/3110834). It enables you to use any color or format for watermark.

Comment: Also using [such code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38450341/3110834) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37949670/3110834) one you can add any other controls to left side or right side of `TextBox`. (For example for that X button)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to create a design near the one in your image but not in the way you want it.

Here's the one I managed to make:

[image: Search]

What I used:

- `textbox` for the search input
- `label` for clearing the input,
- `line shape` (found in `Visual Basic PowerPacks` in the toolbox) for the border effect
  **OR**
- another `label` having a long `underscore` ( _ ).
- and a `picturebox` for the search icon

Procedure:

For the `textbox`, set these properties:

- `BorderStyle : None`
- `BackColor: 0, 188, 212` (or the color of your form's background) but that's the exact color based on the image you provided
- `ForeColor: White`

For the clear button, I just used a `label` (it still has a click event), set the text to: "✖" and the `BackColor` to `Transparent`.

For the `border` effect, just draw a line shape below the `textbox` then set:

- `BorderColor: White`
- `BorderWidth` to `3`

If you are using the `label` with underscores, just place it under the `textbox`.

Sorry got bored that I even included everything even though you're just asking for the `border` (still wondering why did I answer this on the first place). I hope this can still be of any help.